# Why p{Digit} Pattern is not Working in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am using p{Digit} to validade a String. However when I use "101ᶁ1" the result is true. This is happening with some symbols: ᶁ,ﻹ

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Digit}]");
boolean result = p.matcher(value).find();
```

I didn't find the characters that are validated in the documentation.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/lWHocG

Answer (score 1):

I believe you misunderstood the usage of `find()`. It searches for <s>any</s> the first occurrence of the regular expression in the searched text. <sub>(`Pattern.start()` returns the position where the expression was found)</sub>

The expression `"[\\p{Digit}]"` - the `[]` do nothing here - is just matching ONE digit. Since the searched text has a digit, the result of `find()` is `true`.

To match the whole text, the expression must start with `^` to match the beginning of the text and end with `$` corresponding to the end of the text. And it must allow more than one digit, so it needs an `+` (one or more) resulting in

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\p{Digit}+$");
boolean result = p.matcher(value).find();
```

`matches()` can be used to test against the whole text, so `^`  and `$` are not needed - still needs a `+` to allow more than one digit:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Digit}+");
boolean result = p.matcher(value).matches();
```

Note: this can written as:

```
boolean result = value.matches("\\p{Digit}+");
```

Comment: Indeed, I need to check if the character isn't a digit and isn't a punctuation and isn't a latin character. In another words, I need that return false when the string contains ᶁ, for example. I'm trying this pattern:  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\p{IsLatin}\\p{Digit}\\p{Punct}+$");. But, don't work.